# Product titlle display on product image

Tags: product, product-images, image

The product tittle is display at the bottom of the product image and I want to remove it.

[image: View of my problem]

I didn't find any settings in back end and cannot find the code for the display image.

Magento 2.2.4

Comment: Have you using custom theme?

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Magento 2 admin panel and login with your credentials.
2. Go to Stores –> Configuration.
3. Select Developer option from the Advanced tab at the end.
4. Open Debug dropdown and set Enabled Template Path
5. Hints for Storefront to yes. Click to Save Config.

   bin/magento c:c

Go to product page and you see path file when you can delete line code which show title.